# Python Requests | How to stay logged in to a session?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, session-cookies

I want to login to a website and stay logged in to that website to download some file. Downloading those files is not allowed without logging in. How can I prove the website, that I am logged in for another requests? Here is the code I've tried:

```
url = myurl.loginUrl

with requests.Session() as s:

  r = s.get(url,auth=(account_info.username,account_info.password))
  cookie = r.cookies
  headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Girder-OTP': cookie["girderToken"],
  }

  url = myurl.mainPage
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookie)
  cookie = r.cookies
  print(r.status_code)
```

This "r.status_code" returns me 200, which means I am logged in. However, when I try to download files from another url:

```
  url = myurl.downloadUrl
  r = s.get(url,cookies=cookie)
  print(r.status_code)
```

This one returns me 401, which shows that i am unauthorized. 
I've looked for another questions like this, but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to add cookie each time, besides, `r.cookies` may be None because website thinks he should not change your cookie, therefore it may be the reason why you failed to access. And one point you must know `requests.Session()` will automatically share cookie.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.get("http://github.com")
    print(se.cookies)
```

Actually you can save your cookie into file when you exit script. So you just need to load you cookie from file instead of login again. But you need to update your cookie before expire.